# How do I unmount one of two devices mounted to the same mount point?

Tags: linux, operating-system, block

I accidentally left two different devices mounted on `/opt`:

```
/dev/xvdf on /opt type ext4 (rw,relatime,seclabel,data=ordered)
/dev/md0 on /opt type ext4 (rw,relatime,seclabel,stripe=256,data=ordered)
```

It would be a problem to umount `/dev/md0`, and things are using `/opt`. `/dev/md0` should be mounted on top of `/dev/xvdf`. Any suggestions how I can just unmount `/dev/xvdf`?

Tried:

```
[root@redacted ~]# umount /dev/xvdf
umount: /dev/xvdf: umount failed: Invalid argument

[root@redacted ~]# mount --move /dev/xvdf /temp
mount: bad option. Note that moving a mount residing under a shared
       mount is unsupported.
```

Also I've had AWS support for volumes yell at me about force detaching in-use volumes, so that's not an option.

Answer (score 5):

You cannot do it atomically. You can however do it with a sequence of `mount --move` commands. And you will need two other directories to use as mount points.

```
cp /etc/mtab /root/mtab-before
mkdir /mnt/shuffle-md0 /mnt/shuffle-xvdf
mount --move /opt /mnt/shuffle-md0
mount --move /opt /mnt/shuffle-xvdf
mount --move /mnt/shuffle-md0 /opt
umount /mnt/shuffle-xvdf
cp /etc/mtab /root/mtab-after
```

Notice that the `/etc/mtab` entry for `/dev/xvdf` may end up looking pretty weird in the end. So I recommend you create a copy of `/etc/mtab` before you start such that you can reconstruct that entry once you are done.

Anything opening paths through `/opt` while you are shuffling around the mount points may get unexpected results. But files and directories which were opened before you started will be unaffected by this maneuver.

Comment: @SomeLinuxNerd please accept answer if it helped :)

Answer (score 2):

@kasperd solution didn't work for me, because I've received the message:

> It is forbidden to move a mount residing under a shared mount

The easy solution is to comment out the offending mount point in file `/etc/fstab`, and reboot the server.

Comment: The solution to this error might be to switch all mounts into private mode with `mount --make-rprivate /`, execute the moves, and then switch the mounts back into shared mode with `mount --make-rshared /`. Check the propagation states before trying this with `findmnt -o TARGET,PROPAGATION` and adjust accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to run:

```
umount /dev/xvdf /opt
```

Comment: Didn't work, but thanks! umount saw it as a list of things to unmount. TBH there probably is no way of doing this, since /opt is busy anyway.